How to compile DAZ3D plugins to run on Windows 11?
DAZ3D issues a Software Development Kit (SDK) for 32 and 64 bit architectures which has not been maintained for years.  I had great difficulty in compiling even the simplest example plug-in.  What updates are needed to the SDK to allow a software developer to create that plugin to run on Windows 11?
I had downloaded and tried to install the various tools needed by the SDK, with numerous errors.
